# Do I need to launch steam everytime to play Football Manager 2012 on OS X?

Tags: steam, macos, football-manager-2012

Now that we need steam to validate Football Manager 2012, do we need to launch steam everytime we want to play Football Manager 2012?

I am using OS X Snow Leopard.

Thanks.

Comment: yes you have too

Comment: besides your question being answered, launching the game from within steam also provides you with an ingame overlay to chat with friends and quickly google something without having to go completely out of the game. (just a quick tip, therefor a comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to. Otherwise, you can't even launch the game.

Comment: What if you don't have internet?

Comment: you can still play but you have to have to at least had once been online on steam

Comment: Click Steam -> Go Offline to go into offlinemode, You still need steam client on your mac, but you can now play while you're away from the internet.